# Splitting a String and Returning Converted Data

Tags: java

I have 2 Classes, the first one is only used as Container,
and the second Class Splits a GpsString, Converts it to suitable data types and returns the Container Class.

The String to analyze looks about like this:

```
("$GPGGA,120003.533,7926.184,N,02222.419,W,1,12,1.0,88.5,M,0.0,M,,*71")
```

Now i want to know if this is good practice in ObjectOriented Programming,
or if there is a better way for this Problem.

```
final class GpsData {
    int Hours;
    int Minutes;
    double Seconds;
    double Lattitude;
    char DirectionLattitude; // North or South
    double Longitude;
    char DirectionLongitude; // North or South
    int Quality;
    int Satelites;
}


class ProtocolAnalyzer {
    private GpsData AnalyzedData = new GpsData();
    boolean AnalyzeData(String GpsData){
        GpsData Gps = new GpsData();
        int Attribute = 0;
        StringBuilder WorkString = new StringBuilder();
        int beginIndex = 0;
        int length = GpsData.length();
        for (int i = 0;i<=length;i++){
            if(i == GpsData.length() ||
            GpsData.charAt(i) == ','){
            String Data = GpsData.substring(beginIndex,i);
            boolean bool = ConvertData(Data,Attribute,Gps);
            if(!bool) return false;
            beginIndex = i + 1;
            Attribute ++;
        }
    }
    setAnalyzedData(Gps);
    return true;
}
private boolean ConvertData(String Data,int Attribute,GpsData Gps){
boolean b = false;
switch (Attribute) {
    case 0: // §GPGGA
        if(Data.equals("$GPGGA")) {
            b = true;
        }
        break;
    case 1: //HHMMSS.sss
        if(Data.length() == 10) {
            b = true;
            String split = Data.substring(0,2);
            Gps.Hours = Integer.parseInt(split);
            split = Data.substring(2,4);
            Gps.Minutes = Integer.parseInt(split);
            split = Data.substring(4,10);
            Gps.Seconds = Double.parseDouble(split);
        }
        break;
    case 2: //BBBB.BBBB
        if (Data.length() != 0) {
            b = true;
            Gps.Lattitude = Double.parseDouble(Data);
        }
        break;
    case 3: //b
        if (Data.length() != 0) {
            char DirLat = Data.charAt(0);
            if (DirLat == 'N' ||
                    DirLat == 'S') {
                b = true;
                Gps.DirectionLattitude = DirLat;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 4: //LLLLL.LLLL
        if (Data.length() != 0) {
            b = true;
            Gps.Longitude = Double.parseDouble(Data);
        }
        break;
    case 5: //l
        if (Data.length() != 0) {
            char DirLong = Data.charAt(0);
            if (DirLong == 'E' ||
                    DirLong == 'W') {
                b = true;
                Gps.DirectionLongitude = DirLong;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 6: //Q
        if (Data.length() != 0) {
            int Quality = Integer.parseInt(Data);
            Gps.Quality = Quality;
            if(Quality != 0) {
                b = true;
            }
        }
        break;
    case 7: //NN
        if (Data.length() != 0) {
            int Satellites = Integer.parseInt(Data);
            Gps.Satelites = Satellites;
            if(Satellites > 3) {
                b = true;
            }
        }
        break;
}
return b;
}

private void setAnalyzedData(GpsData LogData) {
    this.AnalyzedData = (LogData);
}

GpsData getAnalyzedData() {
    return AnalyzedData;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, *please please please* use Java naming conventions to aid readability. Methods and local variables like `int Hours` should be in `camelCase` and not `CapitalCase` which is for classes. Statements like this:

```
boolean AnalyzeData(String GpsData){
```

are especially confusing. Is `GpsData` referring to the local variable, or the class? That can get very nasty very quickly. Please fix this before you do anything else.

```
final class GpsData {
```

This does not do what I suspect you think it does. A `final` declaration for a class just means it can't be further extended. Its data can still be modified. To properly encapsulate the properties of `GpsData` you should declare each of those properties as `private` and provide `public` constructors, setters, and getters as appropriate.

Comment: Ok i understand, i will use the naming conventions in the future.
But about the setters, getters and constructors, i want to get the whole structure with one getter not multiple ones.

Comment: @Martin.Schloegelhofer avoiding getters does not give you "the whole structure". A simple reference does that either way. However, using getters doesn't provide real encapsulation. It provides a place to set a breakpoint so you can watch someone break your encapsulation. This is good. It's just not encapsulation.

Comment: @candied_orange You are correct, using simple setters is not "encapsulation". But, with setters you can at least incorporate checks to ensure that your data does not enter into an invalid state. At any rate, I was addressing OP's questions of whether what he was doing is "OOP". If he isn't concerned about that, then it's fine of course.

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning that's validation. Getters don't help with that. Setters do. Or preferably  constructors.

Comment: That's what I said?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to think about encapsulating your GPS data to protect it. As Stalemate indicated this means making GpsData class variables private and adding getters, setters and constructors to the class. This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package) may explain why better than I can.